# Position the span with text "my name" next to the circular div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the `span` with text "my name" to stand next to the circular `div`. The `display` property for both are set to `inline-block` but still it is stuck. The code is [in this link](https://jsfiddle.net/rmje7xz3/1/).

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 382px;
  height: 529px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 41px;
  color: white;
  background-color: #de4b4b;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: auto;
}
header span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-left: 172px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-bottom: 14px;
}
.sub-header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 37px;
  background-color: white;
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  color: black;
}
.sub-header span {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.dialog-box1 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 365px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 10px 8px 10px 8px;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.dialog-box1-circle {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: #cccccc;
  margin: 15px 10px 17px 15px;
}
.dialog-box-name {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #6495ED;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 100%;
}
.dialog-box-text {
  color: #cccccc;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-family: 'roboto_light';
  margin-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <header><span>Note</span>
    </header>
    <div class="sub-header"><span>Friday 25.7.13 </span>
    </div>
    <div class="dialog-box1">
      <div class="dialog-box1-circle"></div>
      <span class="dialog-box-name">My Name</span>
      <span class="dialog-box-text">Dont forget to bring the new calender for the meeting.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It is good that you had included your code in question and also provided a fiddle demo. It would have been better if you had formatted your code better :) You could make use of the Stack Snippets for adding HTML/CSS/JS code and can then use the "Tidy" button to correct the formatting. Thanks are generally not required in the question and they are considered as fluff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

delete css display from span

and add css vertical align:middle on the circle

Comment: You should incorporate that into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `display:inline-block` from following rule.

```
.dialog-box-name{
    color:#6495ED;
    font-size:12px;
    width:100%;
    /* display:inline-block; */ // remove this rule
}
```

And Add `vertical-align` css rule

```
.dialog-box1-circle{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    width:35px;
    height:35px;
    border-radius:30px;
    background-color:#cccccc;
    margin:15px 10px 17px 15px;
    vertical-align:middle; /* Add this */

}
```

### [**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/rmje7xz3/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Ok i'm new to answering but here's my answer

remove

display: inline-block;

from

.dialog-box-name

in your CSS

and add

float: left;

to

.dialog-box1-circle

so your CSS would be

```
.container{
position:absolute;
width:382px;
height:529px;
border:1px solid black;
background-color:#cccccc;
}
header{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:41px;
color:white;
background-color:#de4b4b;   
font-weight: bold;
font-size:14px;
margin:auto;


}
header span{
display:inline-block;
padding-left:172px;
padding-top:14px;
padding-bottom:14px;

}
.sub-header{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:37px;
background-color:white;
font-size:10px;
margin:auto;
color:black;


}
.sub-header span{
display:inline-block;
padding-top:14px;
padding-left:10px;
}
.dialog-box1{
position:absolute;
width:365px;    
background-color:white;

margin: 10px 8px 10px 8px;
border:1px solid #cccccc;
}
.dialog-box1-circle{
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
width:35px;
height:35px;
border-radius:30px;
background-color:#cccccc;
margin:15px 10px 17px 15px;
float:left;

}
.dialog-box-name{
color:#6495ED;
font-size:12px;
width:100%;


}
.dialog-box-text{
color:#cccccc;
font-size:10px;
font-family:'roboto_light';
margin-left:15px;

}
```